# PHP MySQL create dump file, change all PKs in database and associated FKs

Tags: php, foreign-keys, primary-key, mysql

In my script, I am copying an entire database from one server to another, and then replicating the values in that database X number of times. I was wondering if there was a way to create a dump file of the new database with PHP, and in that dump file, change all the primary keys to be unique and change the foreign keys to reference the new unique primary keys, and reinsert the dump file into the new database (hence the reason that the primary keys need to be recreated as unique).

Comment: This is the reason why I'm moving to GUIDs rather than autoincrement IDs for my database records

Answer (score 1):

This is a sketch of an answer.

You can read each row of your tables (you must know which fields are PK and 
FKs) and change/replace them accordingly. A php script which migrates DB data to new servers does the same (to replace the base URLS so the DB data can work on the new server). The script reads each DB row, unserialises it if it is serialised, then treated as PHP data and saved back and then dumped.